# Как записать данные в файл JSON, используя Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть страничка html, в ней есть div в нее через JS проходит json...
Так же есть на сервере файл json расширения....
Как мне заставить JS скрипт заполнять файл json расширения jsonом который приходим в div на html страничке???

вот мой ничего не делающий код:

```
let result = document.getElementById('data');
console.log(result);
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = "https://000webhostapp.com/data-model.json";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(result);
    result.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
  }};

xhr.send(result);
```

Comment: обычно это делается на сервере - то есть есть база данных к примеру mariadb - или sqllite но вместо вывода на страницу делается запрос на сохранение в формат json на каком языке это не имеет значение ...javascript не умеет обращаться к базе данных и потому применяют node.js или php или любой другой язык который умеет работать на сервере но javascript работает только в той вкладке которая открыта ..

Comment: и кстати - минусаторы - достаточно просто объяснить а не лепить минусы

Comment: а до этого в панели админа есть форма добавления статей или чего угодно и это всё хозяйство попадает в базу данных откуда мы выводим как нам надо ..но хранение информации в json не хорошая затея ..низкая скорость хотя для общения между серверами удобно

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код выполняет абсолютно противоположную операцию!

-вам надо сначала создать инпут для приёма текста.
-затем на инпут повесить событие change
-по сработке события делать запрос на обработчик
-запись в файл будет в обработчике PHP методом file_put_contents

естественно, никаким js вы не сможете ничего записать в файловую систему сервера)))